# Problem with getting data from query in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have two tables

field_values (with some data)

```
id  field_id  value  label          sort
1       1       1     Men            1
2       1       2     Women          2
3       2       3     Relationship   1
4       2       4     Chat           2
5       2       5     Friendship     3
```

user_interests (with some data)

```
user_id  field_id  value_id
   1        1         1
   1        2         4
   1        2         5
```

I am trying to write a query where I will get user with id 1 and have field_id 2 and to be able to echo in my blade value_id 4 and 5 but not to echo those ids but to echo value of 'label' column that corresponds to value_id form user_interests table in this case 4,5 thus Chat, Friendship from field_values table in this example. Here is what I tried but I get array of six elements which are Relationship, Chat, Friendship x2. Any help is appreciated.

query:

```
public static function queryFunction($userId)
{
    $results = DB::table('user_interests as uin')
        ->select(DB::raw("
            fv.*,
            uin.field_id, uin.value_id
        "))
        ->join('field_values as fv', 'fv.field_id', '=', 'uin.field_id')
        ->where('uin.field_id', 2)
        ->where('uin.user_id', $userId)
        ->get();

        dd($results);

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about 2 clear steps, without join:

`$user_interests = DB::table('user_interests')->select('value_id')->where('field_id', 2)->where('user_id', $userId)->get();`

From this take `values` as array ($user_interests_values)
and than

`$results = DB::table('field_values')->whereIn('value', $user_interests_values)->get();`

Comment: now when I dump $results I get error  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Which object? How did you get `$user_interests_values` array?

Comment: Oh that is probably mistake. I passed $user_interests to whereIn in $results. What should I do with $user_interests_values variable/array?

Comment: `$user_interests_values = $user_interests->pluck('value_id')->toArray();` (or `$user_interests_values = collect($user_interests)->pluck('value_id')->toArray();` if pluck is not working on non model eloquent return, I dont remember)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!